# Get max value from an array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Assuming we have the following documents in our collection:

```
{
  name: 'Product1',
  prices: [
    { shop: 'shop1', price: 1 },
    { shop: 'shop2', price: 2 }
  ]
},
{
  name: 'Product2',
  prices: [
    { shop: 'shop3', price: 5 },
    { shop: 'shop4', price: 3 }
  ]
}
```

I need to get the following results from these documents using mongodb:

```
{
  name: 'Product1',
  bestPrice: { shop: 'shop1', price: 1 }
},
{
  name: 'Product2',
  bestPrice: { shop: 'shop4', price: 3 }
}
```

In other words, I want to get documents with their lowest prices ordered by value of the price field. How could I do it using using mongodb aggregation framework?

Comment: Could you show what you have tried yet

Comment: Anthony, I never tried to create that query, because I don't have an idea what approach should be used to solve this problem. Reading official docs and searching in the internet won't give me answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "bestPrice": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        "$prices",
        {
          "$indexOfArray": [
            "$prices.price",
            { "$min": "$prices.price" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you! About indexes: as I understand, it's enough to have index for prices.price to get best efficiency from this query?

Comment: No you have gone wrong. Indexes only works with `$match` and `$sort` stage. You can read more about it here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/